# Are 3G dongle faster than built-in smartphone 3G chip?

Tags: wireless-networking, 3g

I live on the African continent and do not have access to a cable connection. So whenever I am at home, I rely on my smartphone data plan or on a 3G dongle on my laptop.

I have noticed that the browsing is significantly faster when I'm using my 3g dongle rather than my smartphone.

Could someone explain me why?

I precise that both my smartphone & USB dongle are using the same provider.

Thanks

Comment: There is not enough information to give an answer.  There are *many* factors which could affect speed.

Comment: The difference is your connecting to your phone over potentially slower `WiFi` than a native direct `3G` connection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hmm, that is an ambiguous question, but lets see, why the speed and browsing quality is different between smartphone and a 3G Dongle/Modem.

1) One reason can be that your smartphone might be using some data itself, and thus may result in some overhead which might increase the latency and decrease the overall speed of connection.

2) The bands which your Dongle works on and your smartphone works on can be different, one of them might be experiencing high traffic. (Although this is rare,since most of the carriers use only one band)

3) The receiver/antenna of dongle can be better than that of your smartphone.